# How to check string similarity from two tables with multiple words input in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I have two tables containing a list of company names. The first one would be the index table therefore the value inside would be clean and the format is consistent. The second table contains user-input company information and therefore there might be typos and format inconsistencies.

The first one (the index table) looks similar to this:

```
company_name                         |      industry
Apple Inc                                   Technology
Amazon Inc                                  Retail
Kraft Heinz                                 Food Processing
New York Life Insurance Company             Insurance
Tesla Inc                                   Tesla
Walmart Inc                                 Retail
```

The second table (user input table) looks similar to this

```
company_name
Apple
Apple Inc.
Amazon, Inc
Kraft
New York Life
Tsla
Walmart
```

Notice that the second table does not have the `industry` column since the main goal would be to add the `industry` column to the second table, but since there is no key we can't simply join the two tables.

I think the first step would be to compare the similarity between the `company_name` and if it is similar enough we can just assume it is the same.

I have done some research and I think we would need to use Levenshtein Distance. Honestly, I am not very familiar with that method, but from my limited understanding, I wonder if it is applicable for inputs containing multiple words (e.g New York Life Insurance Company) or it is just effective for one-word input (e.g Apple).

Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check out this tutorial https://towardsdatascience.com/a-journey-into-bigquery-fuzzy-matching-4-of-1-a-tribute-to-fuzzywuzzy-54ff73e91a1c Part 1, Looks at Levenshtein Distance, but part 4 uses this in combination with a token, clean and sort approach which works very nicely. All of which can be achieved with some UDF functions.

Comment: As FYI - using `Levenshtein Distance` alone - matches `New York Life` to `Amazon Inc` instead of expected `New York Life Insurance Company`. So you need to do some extra processing like mentioned in above comment